# Find all root in $x^p \equiv a\pmod q$ where $p$ is any prime number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$x^p \equiv a\pmod q.$ I need to find all roots.

I use Tonelli Shanks algorithm for square degree and find algorithm for cube but for my course work I need algorithm for any prime degree.

Comment: consider a primitive root modoulo $q$ ....

Comment: @TahaAkbari But then you have to solve a [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) to find what power of the primitive root is $a$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes,I just thought $a=1$ at first.Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: I use an experimental method based on closest  $x^p$ to $q$. in this method you find $(q)^\frac 1 p$, you take its floor and plus or minus 1 to get x. you find $r=x^p-q $ and check the exist of primitive roots. For this I use a program in Python. See my answer to my question " has the congruence $x^3 \equiv 84 \ mod 139$ more primitive roots?"